How to re-use a custom function based on Qgis processing tools in another script?
I'm working in QGIS with python script.
I created a script that use processing tools from QGIS using the processing.run(...) function.
Everything worked fine.
Then, I embedded my code in a function to re-use it in another script. So, I modified the code to make it a function (called my_func) and I saved this function in a file (my_function.py). Then, I import it in my new script (import my_function as mf) in a new script (saved in the same folder). I call my function (a = mf.my_func(...)) but I always have this error message:
NameError: name 'processing' is not defined

I tried to import 'procesing' in both of my script but I always have the same problem. What I find strange is that importing my script doesn't seem to make a problem, and I didn't have this problem when I tested the function as a script before.
Does anyone have some idea to solve this issue ?
Thanks!

OK, I finally found a workaround. I created a processing tool based on my function and I used it in the other script.

OK, I finally found a workaround. I created a processing tool based on my function and I used it in the other script.

Hard to tell without seeing your code. It seems you execute your function inside the QGIS python console but if not you have to add the processing path to your python path. Such as : "/path/to/qgis/processing/share/qgis/python/plugins"
Kanash
